# iOS - Peer-to-Peer (p2p) Video Chat, how to connect devices over internet

Tags: ios, p2p, data-transfer, videochat

I am building an app that I want to include a video/voice chat feature.
I already know how to capture video frames as images, audio, etc. which can then be transmitted, but I am curious how to go about connecting 2 devices to each other directly for optimal performance.

I am NOT looking for 3rd party libraries (yes I know about OpenTok, iDoubs, etc etc.). I am just curious how I could accomplish this task from scratch using P2P functionality.

What frameworks or API's are available that could help with connecting devices to each other directly over internet (NOT local wi-fi or bluetooth)?

Comment: You mentioned no 3rd party libraries, but then ask about frameworks/APIs...